# Как запустить sql запрос из тела программы на vb.net

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Всем привет!
Имеется база данных с таблицами, которые наполняются с формы. Нужно собрать данные из всех таблиц в одной. Написал запрос:

```
SELECT        Table1.*, Table10.*, Table11.*, Table12.*, Table13.*, Table14.*, Table2.*, Table3.*, Table5.*, Table4.*, Table6.*, Table7.*, Table8.*, Table9.*
FROM            Table1 LEFT JOIN
                         Table99 ON Table1.Table1ID = Table99.ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table10 ON Table99.ID = Table10.Table10ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table11 ON Table99.ID = Table11.Table11ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table12 ON Table99.ID = Table12.Table12ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table13 ON Table99.ID = Table13.Table13ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table14 ON Table99.ID = Table14.Table14ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table2 ON Table99.ID = Table2.Table2ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table3 ON Table99.ID = Table3.Table3ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table4 ON Table99.ID = Table4.Table4ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table5 ON Table99.ID = Table5.Table5ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table6 ON Table99.ID = Table6.Table6ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table7 ON Table99.ID = Table7.Table7ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table8 ON Table99.ID = Table8.Table8ID LEFT JOIN
                         Table9 ON Table99.ID = Table9.Table9ID
```

Не могу понять как мне его записать. В теле программы через:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connstring2)
Dim query as string = ""
End Using
```

, в хранимой процедуре его писать или для этого есть специальная приблуда в visual studio?

Comment: в представление его лучше запихайте. названия таблиц, конечно, впечатляют.

Comment: Честно говоря, я вообще не рекомендую такое запускать, если таблицы содержат какое-то значимое число строк

Comment: Ok. Вот так его сделал:

Answer (score 0):

Переделал в представление:

```
SELECT        dbo.Table1.Table1ID, dbo.Table1.Adres1, dbo.Table1.Prim1, dbo.Table1.DateS1, dbo.Table1.DateE1, dbo.Table10.Table10ID, dbo.Table10.Adres10, dbo.Table10.Prim10, dbo.Table10.Pogiblo10, dbo.Table10.Postradalo10, 
                         dbo.Table10.DateS10, dbo.Table11.Table11ID, dbo.Table11.Adres11, dbo.Table11.Prim11, dbo.Table11.Pogiblo11, dbo.Table11.Postradalo11, dbo.Table11.DateS11, dbo.Table12.Table12ID, dbo.Table12.Prim12, 
                         dbo.Table12.Lojn, dbo.Table12.Byt, dbo.Table12.Spas, dbo.Table12.DateS12, dbo.Table13.Table13ID, dbo.Table13.Nyp, dbo.Table13.Shtorm, dbo.Table13.Oyp, dbo.Table13.Oksion, dbo.Table13.DateS13, 
                         dbo.Table14.Table14ID, dbo.Table14.Zv60202, dbo.Table14.Prim14, dbo.Table14.FIO, dbo.Table14.DateS14, dbo.Table2.Table2ID, dbo.Table2.Adres2, dbo.Table2.Prim2, dbo.Table2.DateS2, dbo.Table2.DateE2, 
                         dbo.Table3.Table3ID, dbo.Table3.Adres3, dbo.Table3.Prim3, dbo.Table3.DateS3, dbo.Table3.DateE3, dbo.Table5.Table5ID, dbo.Table5.Vozd, dbo.Table5.Vodn, dbo.Table5.DateS5, dbo.Table4.Table4ID, dbo.Table4.Adres4, 
                         dbo.Table4.Prim4, dbo.Table4.DateS4, dbo.Table4.DateE4, dbo.Table6.Table6ID, dbo.Table6.Vlag, dbo.Table6.Davlenie, dbo.Table6.Veter, dbo.Table6.t, dbo.Table6.DateS6, dbo.Table7.Table7ID, dbo.Table7.Adres7, 
                         dbo.Table7.Prim7, dbo.Table7.Pogiblo7, dbo.Table7.Postradalo7, dbo.Table7.DateS7, dbo.Table8.Table8ID, dbo.Table8.Adres8, dbo.Table8.Prim8, dbo.Table8.Pogiblo8, dbo.Table8.Postradalo8, dbo.Table8.DateS8, 
                         dbo.Table9.Table9ID, dbo.Table9.Adres9, dbo.Table9.Prim9, dbo.Table9.Pogiblo9, dbo.Table9.Postradalo9, dbo.Table9.DateS9
FROM            dbo.Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table99 ON dbo.Table1.Table1ID = dbo.Table99.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table10 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table10.Table10ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table11 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table11.Table11ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table12 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table12.Table12ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table13 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table13.Table13ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table14 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table14.Table14ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table2.Table2ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table3 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table3.Table3ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table4 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table4.Table4ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table5 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table5.Table5ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table6 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table6.Table6ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table7 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table7.Table7ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table8 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table8.Table8ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table9 ON dbo.Table99.ID = dbo.Table9.Table9ID
```